# How to Properly Setup an Exit/Panic Button with Multiple Redirects

Tags: button, exit

I have a site that that I've built that is for a Women's Shelter, and it requires the 'exit button' or 'panic button'.. many sites just exit you to Google or another friendly site.. I see a few questions on here that solve the problem in one way or another, but this one my client is most interested in:

http://www.ncadv.org/

Can someone tell me how they're doing this? When you click on the 'safety exit' button, it redirects a BUNCH of times to different sites (thus filling the history quickly with other friendly sites).. I really like this approach, I just can't figure how they're doing it. Any ideas? I'd thought originally they were directing to sites that have their own redirect pages set up, but if you copy the initial link in a new window, it only redirects one time.

Comment: First of all, this is not a properly formatted question. Secondly, why on Earth would you ever want to do this? If I ever clicked a button on a site which redirected me to a dozen unknown sites like that, I would never return.

Comment: @APAD1 I believe the idea is that you can conceal your visit to the original site from a third party (eg an abusive partner) in a hurry, if necessary.

Comment: @APAD1 His reason for needing this is stated in the question and is a GOOD reason.  It is to protect a real person that may be in real, physical danger.

Comment: I upvoted it!  Clearly you don't understand the question.

Comment: Ok, I understand the premise now, but it it is still a poorly posed question. Basically this is just a bunch of websites that the owner has control of and each one redirects to a different site, the last one redirecting to Google. There's no way to do this from just one website, you would have to set up multiple websites with multiple domains and use redirects on each one.

Comment: But it's _not_ redirecting to other sites the owner has.  Take a look at the sites.

Comment: Yes it is, they just purchased a bunch of domains that look like legitimate domain names, which then redirect to the actual site. Notice that the first site it takes you to is abconlinenews.info which then redirects you to the official ABC News site.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying.  That's how they're doing it then; redirect to one 'false' page that redirects to a real one and also opens another false one.  Then that redirects again and so on, and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the responses all. Crazy what they went through for the redirecting of a site.. however, it could save a life.. that's the main thing.

Answer (score 2):

Probably via `HTTP Referer`. To test, run the following in command line:

`curl --header "Referer: http://www.ncadv.org/" http://abconlinenews.info/localnews.php`

The link, `http://abconlinenews.info/localnews.php` is the first outgoing link on the button.

The response (when passed an HTTP referer with `ncadv.org`) is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
    <META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
    <title>ABCNews.com: Daily News, Breaking News and Video Broadcasts - ABC News</title>
    <script>
        function trigger() {
                setTimeout("setPage();",20);
        }
        function setPage() {
            window.location="/localnewstoday.php";          
        }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="trigger();">
        <h1>Not Found</h1>
        <p>The requested URL was not found on this server.</p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at http://abconlinenews.info Port 80</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

From there, it's probably referers and redirects all the way down ;)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might consider is using javascript to keep the history clear.  If you use "location.replace('www.google.com');" for example, it will replace the current entry with the new url and there won't be a history entry to go back to.

If you used a function and passed urls to it via onClick events, you could eliminate any history from being tracked at all.